# using sed to get only line number of "grep -in"

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Which regexp should I use to only get line number from grep -in output?
The usual output is something like this:
241113:keyword

I need to get only "241113" from sed's output.

Comment: +1 to your question **and** to the great answers.  It's really too bad so many people on SO upvote answers without upvoting the question :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest cut

```
 grep -in keyword ... | cut -d: -f1
```

If you insist with sed:

```
 grep -in keyword ... | sed 's/:.*$//g
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use sed. Cut is enough. Just pipe grep's output to

```
cut -d ':' -f 1
```

As an example:

```
grep -n blabla file.txt | cut -d ':' -f 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like awk

```
grep -in 'search' file | awk --field-separator : '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

As said in other answers, `cut` is the right tool; but if you really want to use a swiss-army knife, you can also use `awk`:

```
grep -in keyword ... | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

or using `grep` again:

```
grep -in keyword ... | grep -oE '^[0-9]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is wondering if all this could be done without `grep`, i.e. with `sed` alone ...

```
echo '
a
b
keyword
c
keyWord
x
y
keyword
Keyword
z
' |
sed -n '/[Kk][Ee][Yy][Ww][Oo][Rr][Dd]/{=;}'
#sed -n '/[Kk][Ee][Yy][Ww][Oo][Rr][Dd]/{=;q;}'  # only line number of first match
```